# How implement facebook like button in native swift app after 2/5?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-like, fbsdk

how can implement the facebook like button in a swift app after 2/5?

Facebook said this: 
"Native Like Button: The Native Like Button, designed for mobile apps, will no longer be supported starting with Facebook SDK version 4.28 and above. Previous versions of the SDK can still use the Native Like Button, but starting 2/6, the Native Like Button will no longer be supported. After 2/6, the dialogs for Native Like will no longer appear and taps on any native like button will result in no action."

The original facebook post is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/).
Following the developer's page about facebook like button: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/like-button

Alternatives such as web view without popup window or so on? 
Thanks in advance for the help.